# Define a prefix operator on a Swift tuple

Tags: swift, tuples, prefix-operator

This is probably a `swiftc` bug, but defining a prefix operator on a tuple doesn't seem to work:

```
typealias Pt = (x: Int, y: Int)
prefix func - (p: Pt) -> Pt { return (-p.x, -p.y) }
-Pt(5,6)
```

Results in:

```
error: unary operator '-' cannot be applied to an operand of type '(Int, Int)'
-(5,6)
 ^
```

Is this my bug or Swift's? Or is there a workaround?

Note that defining `Pt` as a struct works fine:

```
struct Pt { var x: Int, y: Int }
prefix func - (p: Pt) -> Pt { return Pt(x: -p.x, y: -p.y) }
-Pt(x: 5, y: 6)  // is equal to Pt(x: -5, y: -6)
```

and that infix operators on tuples work fine too.

Comment: I came across this bug describing this issue, but it hasn't seen any activity or gotten any response: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-294

Comment: Good point. If you change your last line to `(-)(Pt(x: 5, y: 6))` then it works. Sounds bug-like to me.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. I didn't notice it said that in the bug report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind folks; I think this is just a bug.

As I noted in my comment above, there's [this bug filed for it](http://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-294) (which you might vote for if you're having this problem).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that according to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html),

> Classes and structures can provide their own implementations of
>   existing operators.

And a tuple is neither a class nor a structure (with the exception of tuples that have 0 or 1 values, which is the equivalent of Void and the type). For example, if you remove the 'y' component from your tuple, just leaving 'x', then the code compiles.

Comment: Perhaps there's something to what you say, but for one thing you can define the prefix operator without an error; you just can't use it. Secondly, you can define and use infix operators with tuples.

Comment: Yes, I only just noticed your comment that infix operators work. I was just trying it on IBM's sandbox, where your code doesn't compile (edit: it does compile, there's no complain if you define the prefix, but don't use it).